# Breakpoints not getting hit

Tags: firefox

i am using firefox developer 59. I have tried many suggested things, toggling between enable source maps, enable remote debugging, uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox Developer, going into `about:config` and going back to the old debugger, none of these work.

I have been using it for years, now, over the last few months, the breakpoints get hit sometimes, I have to use the `debugger;` JavaScript statement in order to stop at a point in my JavaScript, but even then, at times the watched variables don't show data. and there are times when I cannot even see data from the command line.

Do i really have to put alerts in where I want to see data?

I have read many tutorials, and most tell me how to use the debugger, but none seem to address my problems.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What happened in that last few months? A new project, OS? There are no known bugs in ff dev 59 that does that, have you tried Quantum for example?

Comment: thanks for getting back. i will try to download quantum, but, everything worked as of a few weeks ago on the same projects i have been working on for months.

Comment: Well, judging by the popularity of this question, this could mean that that problem is very localized (to yourself) and there are no visible factors that are causing that to happen. By the way, you know that Chrome debugger is much superior to any of ff? Consider google-ing pros and cons of chrome and ff debugger rather than how to fix that problem you have.

Comment: Thanks will check out chrome along with quantum. 
    In the meantime Sorry for being so verbose, but I what to explain my findings in detail in case SOMEONE ELSE ever comes across this problem OR has seen these symptoms. 
    I went back to the old frontend, I placed a breakpoint on a line and reloaded the page. The breakpoint was not hit. I put javascript debugger in the place before the breakpoint that I set the last time. I reloaded the page. The process stopped at the javascript debugger statement, but my breakpoint disappeared .

Comment: I put the breakpoint back below the javascript debugger statement and clicked the resume. It stopped at my breakpoint. 
     I went back to the new frontend. I started the debugger and at some point, it started loading LOTS (over 40) of “SOURCEsource???” statements in the Breakpoint pane. I had to remove all breakpoints. On to the breakpoint testing. I still had the javascript debugger statement in and I put the breakpoint on the statement after it. I reloaded the page, it stopped at the javascript debugger statement.

Comment: I resumed and the it stopped at the statement with my breakpoint, but, it started loading LOTS (over a 40) of “SOURCEsource???”  AGAIN, I removed all breakpoints again.  I clicked resume, and it loaded more “SOURCEsource???”  AGAIN, I again removed all breakpoints. Next, I took out the javascript debugger statement and still had the breakpoint that was below the now commented out javascript debugger statement to see if it would get hit WITHOUT the javascript debugger statement and I clicked reload the page. It did not stop at my breakpoint,

Comment: but, it loaded LOTS (over a 40) of “SOURCEsource???”  AGAIN
and my breakpoint was gone!! I think these  “SOURCEsource???” wipe out my manually added breakpoints. I thought it had something to do with the “Enable Souce Maps” in the options, so I unchecked it. THAT WAS BAAAAD  because NOW when I try manually adding breakpoint, I click on the line I want a debug statement on, and the breakpoint line number highlights but immediately unhighlights and disappears (everytime I try clicking for a new breakpoint).

Comment: I am using angularjs, the breakpoints i want to hit are in angularjs methods. these breakpoints do not get hit, but the breakpoints in regular js functions DO get hit. apparently there are issues with angularjs because it is dynamically loaded?? I tested this in chrome and firefox quantum. there are plugins to firefox (and chrome) specifically for angularjs - going to check them out now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason i could not set breakpoints inside my angular factories and controller was because i was getting a warning message "Tried to load angular more than once", i was getting this twice. 
first, i took the angular.js out of the partial view that was being called by my SPA. this took out one of the "Tried to load angular more than once".
i saw that the remaining warning msg was because for some reason, my SPA was getting loaded twice. 
second, i moved the angular.js script load to be loaded before anything else (especially any jquery). all of a sudden my SPA was loading once. 
BUT, i still get "Tried to load angular more than once" once. BUT i could drop breakpoints throughout my angularjs. 
now i just have to track down this last "Tried to load angular more than once".